# Databinding to ListView Item in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a user control (WaypointInfoControl) that I wrote that has a dependency property named TheGraphic as shown here:

```
public Graphic TheGraphic
{
    get { return (Graphic)GetValue(TheGraphicProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TheGraphicProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TheGraphicProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TheGraphic", typeof(Graphic), typeof(WaypointInfoControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Graphic)));
```

I have a viewmodel that has a Waypoints property defined like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Graphic>_Waypoints = new GraphicCollection();
public ObservableCollection<Graphic> Waypoints
{
    get { return _Waypoints; }
    set { RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Waypoints, value); }
}
```

In my xaml, I have a ListView that I want to populate with Waypoints:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Waypoints}"  >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate >
       <DataTemplate >
            <controld:WaypointInfoControl TheGraphic="????"   />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How do I bind TheGraphic to the individual item in the ListView that it represents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of `Graphic` objects which means that the `DataContext` for each item in your `ListView` will be a single `Graphic` object. Since the `DependencyProperty` that you are looking to bind to is looking for the `Graphic` object you will just want to bind to the entire `DataContext`, you achieve this by using the binding markup extension without specifying a path (this just causes the binding to pull in the entire `DataContext` which in your case is the Graphic object that you are looking for).

So this should work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Waypoints}"  >
       <ListView.ItemTemplate >
           <DataTemplate >
                <controld:WaypointInfoControl TheGraphic="{Binding}"   />
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```